# JavaFX ComboBox - странное поведение выпадающего списка

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу приложение на JavaFX

Настроил ComboBox так, чтобы его ширина подстраивалась под размеры окна.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane stylesheets="/css/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="desktop_ui.Controller.CommonStatisticController">
    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane maxWidth="300.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                    <children>
                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
                     <children>
                              <Hyperlink alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Общая статистика">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                              </Hyperlink>
                              <Hyperlink alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#setScene" text="Ежедневная статистика">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                              </Hyperlink>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="contentPane">
                    <children>
                  <HBox fx:id="hbox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
                     <children>
                              <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" minWidth="50.0" text="Сайт:">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                              </Label>
                              <ComboBox fx:id="sites" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Выпадающий список в ComboBox некорректно изменяет ширину.

```
public class CommonStatisticController
{

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Choice> sites;

    @FXML
    private TableView<StatisticResultDto> statisticTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StatisticResultDto, Integer> rankColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StatisticResultDto, String> nameColumn;

    /**
     * Сервис для работы с сайтами
     */
    private SiteService siteService;

    /**
     * Сервис для получения статистики
     */
    private StatisticService statisticService;
    private Scene scene;

    public CommonStatisticController()
    {
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        this.siteService = new SiteService();
        this.statisticService = new StatisticService();
        sites.setItems(this.siteService.getAvailableSiteList()); //добавляем значения из ObservableList
        sites.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }
}
```

После запуска приложения выбираем в комбобоксе второе значение, далее разворачиваем окно на весь экран, выбираем снова первое значение, сворачиваем окно обратно и выбираем снова второе значение.

Вот что имеем в результате
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ширина выпадающего списка установилась равной как при развертывании на весь экран и больше не изменяется при любых манипуляциях.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а вас `maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"` у компоненты не смущает?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, данный параметр соответствует `MAX_VALUE` при создании формы через SceneBuilder и позволяет растягивать ComboBox до этого значения при увеличении размера окна при приоритете `hgrow="ALWAYS"`.
Пробовал другие значения для min, pref и max ширины - результат тот же. При определенных манипуляциях с окном ширина выпадающего списка фиксируется и больше не ресайзится под размер самого ComboBox.

Если я не прав - подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Какие значения следует задать?